# pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string array given codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Here is my code

```
$filename = $_FILES[$file_element_name]['name'];

$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Why this line throws an error

> `pathinfo()` expects parameter 1 to be string array given

Comment: `print_r($filename);` check this

Comment: also check what are u getting in `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: You might be uploading multiple files

Comment: @devpro print_r($filename) giving name of the file whatever i want to upload.

Comment: alright, `print_r('your file name hard coded');` test this and remove `PATHINFO_EXTENSION`

Comment: output --Array
(
    [dirname] => .
    [basename] => file.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [filename] => file
) when execute $filename = "file.jpg";
            
            $ext = pathinfo($filename);
        }
        print_r($ext);

Comment: it means its work with hard code, now share the result of `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: i got it by using $filename = $_FILES[$file_element_name]['name'][0]; but i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

> pathinfo() function has two parameters

1. full path eg:/home/users/iages/abc.jpg
2. options  ie, `$options = PATHINFO_DIRNAME or PATHINFO_BASENAME or PATHINFO_EXTENSION or PATHINFO_FILENAME`

if u want to extension of uploaded files use this

```
$_FILES['input field name']['type']
```

or

```
$path = $_FILES['input field name']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$all_files = $_FILES['all_files'];
$temp_name = $all_files["name"];
$file_name = pathinfo($temp_name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
echo $file_name;
```

Hope this will work.